# How do you publish a SCIM 2.0 provisioning app in the G Suite Marketplace?

Tags: google-workspace, google-apps-marketplace, scim, scim2

I'd like to publish an app on the G Suite Marketplace that allows user and group management/provisioning via SCIM 2.0. Where do I need to go to configure that?

This article from 2016 made me think it would be possible (https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2016/07/automatically-provision-users-with-scim.html) but I cannot find it anywhere in Google's documentation or Marketplace SDK?

We currently user SCIM as our primary method for integrating with the Identity Providers used by our enterprise clients. Some enterprises use GSuite for SSO though. Our current app in the Google Marketplace doesn't use SCIM and therefore has to be maintained separately.

Comment: were you able to find docs for this?